# Method Save() Laravel 5.6, returning True or False

Tags: laravel, exception, error-handling

I have a method that performs the registration, this method can not display errors to the user, would like to return only true or false, so that other functions take the necessary action.
I'm doing this, but the record always returns false, how should I do?

$table->string('fieldWithError', 10);//This field has error purpose

```
try{
   $user = new User;
   $user->fields = 'example';
   $user->fieldWithError = 'Example exceeds characters DB';// This field is incorrect
   $user->save();
}
catch(\Exception $e){
   return false;
}
```

if the fieldWithError field is incorrect, I want to return false and not write to the database, if it is correct I want to write to the database and return TRUE.

Comment: why don't you use [validations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `return true` after a piece of code that is expected to throw the exception, for example: (this way the function that calls this code gets a false on any exception, or else true)

```
try{
   $user = new User;
   $user->fields = 'example';
   $user->fieldWithError = 'Example exceeds characters DB';// This field is incorrect
   $user->save();
   return true;
}
catch(\Exception $e){
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works for me.

I`m a beginner programmer and laravel, some concepts are still difficult for me.

Comment: @HelderFerrari no worries, we all were once, happy to help :)

Comment: @HelderFerrari but as ab_ab mentioned, it would be better to validate the content before insertion, instead of 'inserting anything' and waiting for an exception

Comment: Yes, I'm validating before sending to model, so i needed the return True or False :)

Comment: @HelderFerrari 